# Intellij Idea and deploying to weblogic

Tags: deployment, intellij-idea, weblogic12c

I did not use to work with weblogic before, but I have to do it now. I use Intellij Idea and I have configuration file for weblogic written by another person.
But Idea does not work well with it as you can see on the picture below. Deploying does not work too with exception:

```
DeploymentException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer.startFinalizer
```

What might be the problem?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok seems like I have found solution. I had to add those schemas to Idea settings.
You can also do this by pressing Alt+Enter
[image: Picture]